# Java 1.8.40 Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, serversocket, sslhandshakeexception

I have standalone Java `Server Socket application` running on Java 1.8.40 as windows service, and we have a Spring web application as Client which performs SSL handshake with `selfsigned SHA1 RSA 2048` certificate with the `Server Socket application` then performs other actions. We do have the same `selfsigned SHA1 RSA 2048` cert in the `Server Socket application` keystore.jks.

Am seeing a weird issue with my `Server Socket application` in Production, randomly its throwing below exception and Java client is getting `Peer not authenticated` exception. if I restart the `Server Socket application` I dont see the below exception and Java client can perform the SSL handshake succesfully

```
com.ssltunnel.server.MainServerHandshakeThread | IO Error waiting for handshake
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.ssltunnel.server.MainServerHandshakeThread.handshake(MainServerHandshakeThread.java:41)
at com.ssltunnel.server.MainServerHandshakeThread.run(MainServerHandshakeThread.java:71)
at com.ssltunnel.utilities.threading.ShutdownThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ShutdownThreadPoolExecutor.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkClientTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
... 22 more
```

**Below is my MainServerHandshakeThread**

```
public class MainServerHandshakeThread implements Runnable {

    private final Socket clientSocket;
    private final MainServer server;
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainServerHandshakeThread.class.getName());
    private boolean done;
    private static final long TIMEOUT= 10000000000L;
    public static final int NSTOMS = 1000000;

    public MainServerHandshakeThread(Socket clientSocket, MainServer server) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.server = server;
    }

    private void handshake() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClientNotFoundException {

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        // Changed to want to allow for diagnosing bad certificates
        ((SSLSocket) clientSocket).setNeedClientAuth(true);
        MainServerHandshakeHandler handshake = new MainServerHandshakeHandler();
        ((SSLSocket) clientSocket).addHandshakeCompletedListener(handshake);
        ((SSLSocket) clientSocket).startHandshake(); //Line# 41


        while (!handshake.isDone() && !done) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            long duration = System.nanoTime() - start;
            if (duration>TIMEOUT) {
                done = true;
                LOG.warn("Handshake timeout");
            }
        }
        long stop = System.nanoTime();
        LOG.debug("Handshake done in ms: " + ((stop - start) / NSTOMS) );
        String serialNumber = handshake.getSerialNumber();
        LOG.debug(serialNumber);


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            handshake();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.error("IO Error waiting for handshake", ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOG.error("Interrupted waiting for handshake", ex);
        } catch (ClientNotFoundException ex) {
            LOG.warn("Client not found",ex);
        } finally {
            LOG.debug("Handshake thread is done");
            done = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        if (clientSocket!=null) {
            SocketUtils.closeQuietly(clientSocket);
        }
    }
}
```

We do have the truststore and keystore configured in the Server Socket application as below

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/server/conf/keystore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", KEYSTOREPASS);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:/server/conf/keystore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KEYSTOREPASS);
```

Since the issue is fixing with the restart we are doing restart whenever this issue happens in Production. We want to avoid this and fix this issue, can someone pleae help me how to fix this random issue?

Comment: Have you checked that you have a synchronized NTP reference on your client and server hosts?

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo I did verify that Server and Client clocks are in sync